# Setting image src is not async in setInterval

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am creating an animation by using setInterval.

```
    var roman_numeral = document.getElementById('roman_numeral');
    var i = 1
    var generation = 1
    var preload;
    setInterval( async function (a) {
        
        roman_numeral.innerHTML = romanize(i);
        console.log(i);
        if(i == 1){
            preload = new Preloader(generation+1, "generation")
            console.log("The code stops here");
            //The code waits here; Seems like synchronus
        }
        i++
        
        if(i == 1000){
            i = 1;
            
            generation ++;
            preload.add()
        }

        if(generation == 1035){
            i = 1;
            generation = 1
        }
    }, 10)
```

I made a class for preloading images, but when creating a new instance of the class, the setInterval seems to run synchronus.

```
class Preloader {
  
    constructor(gen, attach_id) {
        this.gen = gen
        this.attach_id = attach_id
        this.preload();
    }

   async preload() {
        let container = document.getElementById("generation_animation");
        let preload_img = document.createElement("img");
        preload_img.style.display = "none";
        preload_img.style.width = "0px";
        
        preload_img.id= "preload_generation";
        preload_img.setAttribute("loading", "lazy")
        container.appendChild(preload_img);
        preload_img.src = "res/img/Generations/" + this.gen.toString() + ".png";
        container.appendChild(preload_img)
        console.log("aaaaaaaa");
    }

    add() {
        let previous = document.getElementById("generation")
       
        let current = document.getElementById("preload_generation");
        current.style.width = "50%";
        current.style.display = "";
        current.classList.add("generations_class");
        current.id = "generation";
        previous.remove();
        

    }
}
```

I want to load the image while performing the setInterval loop. How would i do that?

Comment: There's no reason for you to be using `async` on those functions.

Comment: @Andy I was desperate and tried many different approaches, but yes it is unnecessary.

Comment: Why not load the images into an array first, and then iterate over that to get your animation.

Comment: @Andy It is 1035 images with 1.3 mb each

Comment: You can use the `onload` event (`preload_img.onload = () => { ... }`) to execute code when the image has fully loaded.

Comment: Then could you not create an animation from those images, and then load that up as a webm or something? The way you're approaching this sounds very inefficient. Because, that's well over a _gigabyte_ of images which, frankly, is unreasonable, even for someone with a decent network connection.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus I want to load images while having the animation. Wouldnt onload do the opposite?

Comment: @Andy I have thought of that, but it would take to much time to do so. Each image has 1000 different roman numerals, which means I need to animate 1035000 images

Comment: @EliasKnudsen you have to wait until at least a few (ideally all) of the images have fully loaded before starting the animation right? Currently (as I see it) you have no way of knowing when to start.

Comment: You should probably try to reframe your question then with this new information. But 1.3MB per image is way too much..

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus Yea, my goal is to load the next image, and then using it when the conditions in the loop are met.

Comment: @Andy I know, but they are for tshirt prints. I could make another set with lower resolutions though.